# How to use pv command in a backup

Tags: shell, ubuntu, server, sh

I am doing a backup `dd if=/dev/vda1 | lzop > /etc/BACKUP/im.lzo` and I want to see the progress bar using the command `pv` but I don't know what the correct syntax for this is.

I have tried:

1. `pv dd if=/dev/vda1 | lzop > /etc/BACKUP/im.lzo`
2. `dd if=/dev/vda1 | lzop > pv /etc/BACKUP/im.lzo`
3. `dd if=/dev/vda1 | pv lzop > /etc/BACKUP/im.lzo`

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You must pipe your output to `pv`, which will then re-send it to standard output:

```
dd if=/dev/vda1 | pv | lzop > /etc/BACKUP/im.lzo
```

Comment: You could even do `dd | pv | lzop | pv >file`